# Date in p:chart subtracting client's timezone offset

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jqplot

I have a graph which has dates on x-axis. The problem is that it is subtracting client browser's timezone offset from all the dates.
For a quick fix, if I subtract this offset from dates and then if Day Light Saving has occurred in between the dates then dates after DST shift becomes correct because of subtraction and dates before the DST shift becomes incorrect.
e.g. GB is 1 hour offset from GMT. If I subtract 1 from all dates and my graph is showing data from 15th March to 15th April. Day light saving has been observed from 26th March so dates after it gets correct by subtracting 1 but dates before it becomes 1 hour less as before dates don't need any offset.

I am using Primefaces 5.2 and Java 7.

Comment: Tried PrimeFaces 6.1 (maybe it contains a newer jqplot) and are you sure the client does this (you see the right dates in the json in the client)?

Comment: Yes I tried to print the dates and have seen that jqplot does this.

Comment: Then please check the jqplot site/forums to